# How to use all register banks of 8051 at a single time?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

I am aware that we can set only one active bank at a time for 8051 using `PSW.4` and `PSW.3`, but is it in some way or trick possible to achieve selection of all banks at once?

Comment: What would that do? You can't do that. Since registers are memory mapped you can however access all of them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least *address the register's name **directly*** in an instruction. That's because 8051 instructions were designed to be encoded with a single byte, or a byte plus an immediate. That byte contains the opcode and 3 bits for the register number. Thus you can only encode 8 registers in the instruction

The registers are put in the general purpose memory region though, so you can access them at any time using memory access instructions. Of course that limits what you can do with registers in a different bank. For example you can move the R5 in bank 0 to the current R3 with `MOV R3, 05h` because bank 0 lies in the address range 00h-07h

> 8 general-purpose registers R0–R7 may be accessed with instructions 1 byte shorter than others. They are mapped to IRAM between 0x00 and 0x1F. Only 8 bytes of that range are used at any given time, determined by the two bank select bits in the PSW.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51#Registers

[Banking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_switching) is a simple way to [increase the total addressable memory with a limited address range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21385250/995714). Here Intel used it to address 32 registers with 3 bits, but of course you can access only 8 of them at a time. But some instructions have even fewer bits to encode the registers and you can only specify R0 or R1 like `MOV @R0/1,#data`

See also

- [Intel MCS-51's Instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51#Instruction_set)
- [8051 Instruction Set](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/comp/8051/set8051.html)
- [Why 8051 don't have R0 to R32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19052746/995714)